# UI alternatives for Drag & Drop

Tags: user-interface, drag-and-drop

I'm implementing Drag & Drop for an application of mine so a user can drag some item to a folder. Regardless of the programming language/Gui Framework I used I never liked implementing Drag & Drop code at all.

Further I often see computer users who don't use Drag & Drop if you don't tell them exactly how it works. They are searchig for an "Add"-Button instead of just dragging the item to the folder for instance (I have seen this in iTunes several times).

So I ask myself if there isn't a better alternative to the Drag & Drop paradigm. You could for instance blend in context sensitive buttons near every item when a folder is highlighted. The button-click would then add the item. Usability-wise not the best example but maybe you know better ones.

Do you know nice alternatives, applications that implement this "item-to-folder-functionality" without resorting to Drag & Drop?

Comment: honestly I never met a person who knew how to use computer and didn't know what "drag and drop" means. it is kinda self explanatory :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes me think of the 'Move to' function in GMail. You select the messages your want to move with the checkboxes. On top, there is a dropdown button (with autocomplete support to easily locate the label you want) that allows you to move the messages to the label/folder. No drag and drop and intuative indeed.

(That said, I find DnD very natural, I definitely would consider it if building a GUI)

Comment: The key to designing a good UI is always "copy Apple or Google."

Comment: Yeah, the GMail functionality works but always felt a little clunky to me. I suppose one really can't live without Drag & Drop but it can't hurt to search for alternatives. ;)